# Spark Array is empty after iteration

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark

In spark 1.6.0(I am not very familiar with spark and scala) when I iterate over a collection and add items to an array when the iteration is over the array seems to be empty.

```
var testing = unlabeled.map { line =>
  val parts = line.split(',')
  val text = parts(7).split(' ')
  (line, htf.transform(text))
}

var lowPropQueue = new mutable.ArrayBuffer[(String, org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector)]
var highPropQueue = new mutable.ArrayBuffer[(String, org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector)]

for(counter <- 1 to 5){

  logger.info("this is the " + counter + " run -----------------")
  for (i <- testing) {
    val label = model.predict(i._2).toString
    //        logger.info(i._1.split(",")(7))
    //        logger.info(label)
    var probs = model.predictProbabilities(i._2)
    logger.info("prob 0 : " + probs(0))
    logger.info("prob 1 : " + probs(1))
    logger.info("--------------------- ")

    if (probs(0).toDouble <= 0.95 && probs(1).toDouble <= 0.95 ) {
      lowPropQueue.+=(i)
    } else {
      highPropQueue.+=((i._1 + "," + label , i._2))
    }

    logger.info("size of high array : " + highPropQueue.length)
    logger.info("size of low array : " + lowPropQueue.length)

  }

  logger.info("passed: " + lowPropQueue.length)
  logger.info("NOT passed: " + highPropQueue.length)

  var xx=  sc.parallelize(highPropQueue).collect()
  var yy = sc.parallelize(lowPropQueue).collect()

  logger.info("passed: " + xx.length)
  logger.info("NOT passed: " + yy.length)
...
}
```

but based on the logs the inner loop seems to add elements to the Arrays, i.e.:

> 16/10/11 11:22:31 INFO SelfLearningMNB$: size of high array : 500
>
> 16/10/11 11:22:31 INFO SelfLearningMNB$: size of low array : 83
>
> 16/10/11 11:22:31 INFO SelfLearningMNB$: prob 0 : 0.37094327822665185
>
> 16/10/11 11:22:31 INFO SelfLearningMNB$: prob 1 : 0.6290567217733481
>
> 16/10/11 11:22:31 INFO SelfLearningMNB$: ---------------------
>
> 16/10/11 11:22:31 INFO SelfLearningMNB$: size of high array : 500
>
> 16/10/11 11:22:31 INFO SelfLearningMNB$: size of low array : 84
>
> 16/10/11 11:22:31 INFO SelfLearningMNB$: prob 0 : 0.16872929936216619
>
> 16/10/11 11:22:31 INFO SelfLearningMNB$: prob 1 : 0.8312707006378338

But when the inner loop ends I get this:

> 16/10/11 11:43:53 INFO SelfLearningMNB$: passed: 0
>
> 16/10/11 11:43:53 INFO SelfLearningMNB$: NOT passed: 0

What is going on ?

**EDIT**

How can you obtain the data from executors or save data from executors to HDFS so they can be read from master node later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL; DR** This cannot work in Spark.

> What is going on ?

- each executor gets its own copy of `lowPropQueue`, `highPropQueue`.
- during iteration local copies are modified
- after iteration local copies are discarded

FYI Naive append to `ArrayBuffer` is not thread safe.

Comment: I though about that. But how is it possible to store the data from executors to a "global" array ?

Comment: You can try accumulators but you'd need synchronized access and looking at your code it just won't scale.

Comment: I did some search and this approach definitely is not appropriate for Spark. I had to map everything but it worked.